# Select rows of a dataframe based on another dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})
print(df1)

    A      B   C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
1  bar    one  1   2
2  foo    two  2   4
3  bar  three  3   6
4  foo    two  4   8
5  bar    two  5  10
6  foo    one  6  12
7  foo  three  7  14
```

I hope to select rows in `df1` by the `df2` as follows:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar'.split(),
                   'B': 'one two'.split()
                   })
print(df2)

     A    B
0  foo  one
1  bar  two
```

Here is what I have tried in Python, but I just wonder if there is another method. Thanks.

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['A','B'])
print(df)
```

This is the output expected.

```
    A      B   C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
1  bar    two  5  10
2  foo    one  6  12
```

[Using pandas to select rows using two different columns from dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937022/using-pandas-to-select-rows-using-two-different-columns-from-dataframe)

[Select Columns of a DataFrame based on another DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52163161/select-columns-of-a-dataframe-based-on-another-dataframe)

Comment: what's wrong with current method?

Comment: In my opinion it is good solution.

Comment: I think maybe we can try with loc, iloc or isin function, what do you think?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937022/using-pandas-to-select-rows-using-two-different-columns-from-dataframe

Comment: Sorry maybe i ask a silly question.

Comment: Code that works belong in code review. But sincerely I don't think a review would bring much, I think you did fine there

Comment: Agree with jezrael and Arthur. it is fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simpliest is use `merge` with inner join.

Another solution with filtering:

```
arr = [np.array([df1[k] == v for k, v in x.items()]).all(axis=0) for x in df2.to_dict('r')]
df = df1[np.array(arr).any(axis=0)]
print(df)
     A    B  C   D
0  foo  one  0   0
5  bar  two  5  10
6  foo  one  6  12
```

Or create `MultiIndex` and filter with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df = df1[df1.set_index(['A','B']).index.isin(df2.set_index(['A','B']).index)]
print(df)
     A    B  C   D
0  foo  one  0   0
5  bar  two  5  10
6  foo  one  6  12
```

Comment: Sincere thanks and great respect to Python masters who give comments and helps here!! ;)

Comment: @ahbon - yes, and super thing is there is a lot of masters of pandas, so a lot of answers are answered ;) Happy coding!

Comment: Your second solution is awesome!! Solve problem on one line and it's the answer expected.

Comment: @ahbon - yes, it is better :)

Answer (score 3):

Method #4. `.apply` + `key` function:

```py
>>> key = lambda row: (row.A, row.B)
>>> df1[df1.apply(key, axis=1).isin(df2.apply(key, axis=1))]
     A    B  C   D
0  foo  one  0   0
5  bar  two  5  10
6  foo  one  6  12
```

Method #5. `.join`:

```py
>>> df1.join(df2.set_index(['A', 'B']), on=['A', 'B'], how='right')
     A    B  C   D
0  foo  one  0   0
6  foo  one  6  12
5  bar  two  5  10
```

Methods already mentioned:

1. `.merge` by [@ahbon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54006298/7204581)
2. Filtering with `.to_dict('records')` by [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54006502/7204581) (fastest)
3. `Index.isin` by [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54006502/7204581)

Performance comparison (fastest to slowest):

```py
>>> %%timeit
>>> df1[np.array([np.array([df1[k] == v for k, v in x.items()]).all(axis=0) for x in df2.to_dict('records')]).any(axis=0)]
1.62 ms ± 15.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> key = lambda row: (row.A, row.B)
>>> %%timeit
>>> df1[df1.apply(key, axis=1).isin(df2.apply(key, axis=1))]
2.96 ms ± 408 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %%timeit
>>> df1.merge(df2, on=['A','B'])
3.15 ms ± 472 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %%timeit
>>> df1.join(df2.set_index(['A', 'B']), on=['A', 'B'], how='right')
3.97 ms ± 341 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %%timeit
>>> df1[df1.set_index(['A','B']).index.isin(df2.set_index(['A','B']).index)]
6.55 ms ± 391 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: The error I see with simple approach is "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"  So it is necessary to set index.  This approach handles that and *it works*.  It the best.

Answer (score 1):

```
# The .merge method performs an inner join by default. 
# The resulting dataframe will only have rows where the 
# merge column value exists in both dataframes

x = df_only_english.merge(train_orders.assign(id=train_orders.id))
x

Unnamed: 0  language    score   id  iso_language_name   is_en   cell_order
0   0   en  0.999998    00015c83e2717b  English English 2e94bd7a 3e99dee9 b5e286ea da4f7550 c417225b 51e3cd89 2600b4eb 75b65993 cf195f8b 25699d02 72b3201a f2c750d3 de148b56...
1   1   en  0.999999    0001bdd4021779  English English 3fdc37be 073782ca 8ea7263c 80543cd8 38310c80 073e27e5 015d52a4 ad7679ef 7fde4f04 07c52510 0a1a7a39 0bcd3fef 58bf360b
2   2   en  0.999996    0001daf4c2c76d  English English 97266564 a898e555 86605076 76cc2642 ef279279 df6c939f 2476da96 00f87d0a ae93e8e6 58aadb1d d20b0094 986fd4f1 b4ff1015...
```